# Retrofit POST Request authentication token not accepting

Tags: android, curl, http-post, retrofit

I am trying to send a POST Request to a REST API which I created. For this I am using Retrofit.

Now when I send the request using CURL commands in terminal, the request get accepted and the values are stored. Below is the code:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "X-User-Email: abcd@gmail.com" -H "X-User-Token: qQsQobQv-Wmum7bUs4b_"  -X POST -d '{"store": {"code":"0010" } }' http://localhost:3000/api/store.json
```

The above works completely fine.

Now when I try to send the request using Retrofit in my android app, it says Unauthorization Error in my API. And nothing gets stored.

```
final String endpoint = "http://localhost:3000/api/store.json"
RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor = new RequestInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
                request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                request.addHeader("X-User-Email", email);
                request.addHeader("X-User-Token", auth_token);
            }
        };

        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(endpoint)
                .setRequestInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
                .build();

        Service service = restAdapter.create(Service.class);
        service.store(fault, new Callback<StoreResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void success(StoreResponse storeResponse, Response response) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Success");
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Failure" + error.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

This doesn't work. I don't know what to do. Been stuck here for a while.
Please help!!!

Here is the Service Class:

```
public interface Service {
    @POST("/")
    public void store(@Body StoreResponse fault, Callback<StoreResponse> responseCallback);
}
```

## EDIT

It is working fine now. Actually my email was not getting stored and so the variable was null. Fixed that and now everything is working fine.

Comment: Post your Service class, please

Comment: I have edited my question. Please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your "test" class as follow:

```
final String endpoint = "http://localhost:3000/api"

RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(endpoint)
                .build();

Service service = restAdapter.create(Service.class);
service.store(fault, new Callback<StoreResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void success(StoreResponse storeResponse, Response response) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Success");
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Failure" + error.getMessage());
    }
});
```

And your Service interface:

```
public interface Service {
   @Headers({"X-User-Email: abcd@gmail.com", "X-User-Token: qQsQobQv-Wmum7bUs4b_"})
   @POST("/store.json")
   public void store(@Body StoreResponse fault, Callback<StoreResponse> responseCallback);
}
```

Or if you need headers with dynamic values:

```
public interface Service {
   @POST("/store.json")
   public void store(@Header("X-User-Email") String email, @Header("X-User-Token") String token, @Body StoreResponse fault, Callback<StoreResponse> responseCallback);
}
```

Comment: But how can I implement dynamic parameters in Header in this solution??
X-User-Token can change number of times, and that is the reason I used RequestInterceptor. And also email id will vary according to the user it cannot be constant.

Comment: I've edited my question. Take a look please. Anyway, are you sure that the values of your credentials are the appropriates one??

Comment: I've tried the last part. Still it is showing Unauthorized user. Not taking the auth token or something like that. Or the post request is not up to the mark.

Comment: It is showing 401 Unauthorized error. Why would this come ??
Is it something that is wrong with Retrofit classes?

Comment: Ohh It is working fine. And with all the techniques. The problem was my email was not getting stored and so it was null.That is why it was showing unauthorized error. Thanks for your help Victor!